# How to make a nested object out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

given an array like `[‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’]`

how can i get an object like

```
{
  current: ‘a’,
  next : { 
    current: ‘b’,
    next: {
      current: ‘c’
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a recursive function for this:

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function createObj([current, ...rest]) {
    const result = { current };
    if (rest.length) result.next = createObj(rest);
    return result;
}

console.log(createObj(data));
```

*The `[current, ...rest]` is a single [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) array argument.*

Comment: i ended up using this answer as it also translates to other languages easily

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Array.reduceRight()` to create the object:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const obj = arr.reduceRight((acc, o) => ({
  current: o,
  ...acc && { next: acc }
}), null)

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: both answers are good, i’m not sure which to select

Comment: lol. Try them both for your use case, and see which is more readable, and works better for you.